# Ошибка получения списка с сайта

Tags: docker, kubernetes

У меня установлен docker freescout в kubernetes, а именно microk8s, и когда я захожу в раздел модулей, список модулей пуст, а в середине экрана появляется надпись "Потеряно подключение к Интернету". Чтобы проверить интернет соединение, я зашел внутрь контейнера и проверил сайт freescout.net и google.com и все было прекрасно, пинг проходил успешно:

`[tiredofit/freescout:1.17.10 13:41:19 /] $ ping freescout.net`

`PING freescout.net (104.248.19.129) 56(84) bytes of data.`

`64 bytes from freescout.net (104.248.19.129): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=50.1 ms`

Просмотрев логи, нашёл такую ошибку:

`WpApi Error: cURL error 28: Failed to connect to 0.0.0.1 port 1080 after 10000 ms: Timeout was reached (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html); File: /www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php (185)`

Окружающая среда:

tiredofit/freescout:latest, Ubuntu 20.04, MicroK8s v1.26.5 редакция 5395,

Что может быть не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Друзья, проблема решилась сменой "true" на "false" в переменной "APP_PROXY". В описании есть эта переменная

[Docker hub - Freescout](https://hub.docker.com/r/tiredofit/freescout)